# How to convert an array to comma-separated string with placeholders for each array item?

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I have a variable `$input` that contains an array with a variable number of items.

How can I create a comma-separated string of this showing a question mark for each value and quotation marks around each question mark as in the example below?

I tried using the following but this wraps all question marks in one quotation mark instead of having the quotation marks around each question mark:

My attempt:

```
$output = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($input), "?"));
```

Example array:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

Expected output:

```
$output = "?", "?", "?", "?", "?"
```

Current output:

```
$output = "?, ?, ?, ?, ?"
```

Comment: `$output = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($input), "?"));` won't wrap anything in quotes.... something else in your code must be putting the quotes around $output; but if you need quotes use `$output = implode('", "', array_fill(0, count($input), "?"));`

Comment: @MarkBaker: Thanks. This was just meant to show the difference between current and expected output here, sorry. What I meant is that I need the quotation marks around each question mark.

Comment: @MarkBaker: I tried your approach and this is close to what I need but here the output is missing opening quotes for the first question mark and closing quotes for the last one.

Comment: Alright, I thought you could figure out a simple string concatenation yourself. Full answer: `$output = '"' . implode('", "', array_fill(0, count($input), "?")) .'"';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$output = implode( ", ", array_fill(0, count($input), "\"?\"" ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

https://eval.in/401410

**CODE**

```
<?php 
$K= array("1","2","3","4","5");
$P=preg_filter('/^(.*)/', '"?"', $K);
echo implode(",",$P);
?>
```

Comment: `preg_filter()` is not appropriate here because there is no actual filtering occuring -- just use `preg_replace()` if you need to replace with a regex.  Clearly `array_fill()` or `str_repeat()` (with trimming afterward) is better suited.